# Is there anything similar to LocalAuthentication for iWatch applications?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, watchos, localauthentication

On iPhone apps, if we want to authenticate app with default authentication which is using to unlock iPhone, Apple provides the framework called 'LocalAuthentication'.

By using these we can authenticate our app via :

- Passcode
- Touch ID
- Face ID

I want to know is there anything similar for watch apps in watchOS ?

I want to authenticate my stand alone iWatch app with the passcode which used to unlock the iWatch.

Comment: No, since the watch is a personal device it is always unlocked until the user removes it from their wrist (assuming they have wrist detection enabled). There is no local authentication framework for watchOS as such a flow is not a "watch experience"

Comment: Correct, but after wear it off it required passcode to unlock...right. I just want to use same to open and further use of my iWatch  app.

Comment: That isn't available for watchOS apps.

Comment: found any solution?